# Emulate a network connection in Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, windows-8.1, visual-studio

I have no idea if it's possible but I need a way to simulate a network adapter that thinks it is connected. The issue is that I am trying to give my Windows Phone 8 emulator internet access through my laptop's wifi connection and this is as far as I could determine the only way that I will be able to achieve this.

The problem is that by default in order for the hyper-v based emulator to gain internet access Visual Studio creates an external virtual network switch and then bridges it with the wireless adapter. It seems this worked on Windows 8 but on Windows 8.1 it seems to break DHCP capabilities on the adapters, this means that I have to assign an ip manually for my laptop to regain internet access but unfortunately the emulator does not support manually assigning an ip address and thus does not manage to achieve an internet connection. An Ethernet based connection works fine though.

I have though managed to get an internet connection on the emulator whilst launching it from the hyper-v manager. To do so though I had first created an internal network switch for the emulator and then shared my internet connection with that network and then add this switch to the virtual machine. The problem is that Visual Studio does not like this and removes the network switch from the virtual machine once it is started. The thing is as far a I can determine that Visual Studio only allows the virtual machine to be connected to an external switch which is connected to an active network adapter as in once I unplug my Ethernet connector Visual Studio does not allow the virtual machine to be connected to the switch connected to the Ethernet adapter anymore.

What I think will solve the problem is that if I can somehow emulate an active network connection and create a switch to it that I can then connect to the virtual machine then I can simply share my wifi internet connection with said switch. The emulated connection obviously does not require an internet connection and should not really be connected to anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you reinstall all software used to verify the problem isn't with your configuration because I am not current experiencing your problems and know of no technical reason the emulator would behave differently on Windows 8.0 vs Windows 8.1

Comment: I have updated VS since upgrading to Windows 8.1 but I am still downloading the latest installer for VS (slow internet) so I have not reinstalled it yet. I can try the old installer I used on Win 8 but I don't know if it will help. I have though uninstalled and reinstalled hyper-h already.